# Wrong results from DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I receive a string representing a date in the format *YmdHis*. When I turn it into a `DateTime` object and print it back out I get the timestamp for "now". Why is this happening?

```
$time = '20140718121314';
$format = 'YmdHis';

$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->createFromFormat($format, $time)

$dt->format($format); // equals 20140731001832 (i.e. 'now')
```

Answer (score 1):

[createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is static method. Example of usage:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time);
```

[About static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24795599/1503018)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's an order of operations issue. The timezone has to be set *after* `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.